# ionic page data does not update

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

So say i have page one:

This page contains multiple variables and a constructor. it could look something like this:

```
export class TestPage implements OnInit {

    testInt: number;
    testString: string;
    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.testInt = this.someService.getInt();
        this.testString = this.someService.getLongText();
    }

}
```

Now when this page loads it correctly sets the values.

Now say that I change page and on this page, I change some of the values in the service.

When I then come pack to this `TestPage` it hasn't updated the values.

Does this have something to do with caching? or with push state?

How can I make sure that the page is "reloaded" ?

Comment: Don't use the constructor for setting values, use the Angular Lifecycle Hooks - namely ngOnInit

Comment: @xdecdec i moved the code to ngOnInit however sadly with same result. il update the code example

Comment: https://saniyusuf.com/ionic-by-component-page-lifecycle/

Comment: @JGFMK this makes sense however how do i make sure i implement it correctly? is there something i should implement in my class or how does it work?

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle :)

Comment: It's been a few yrs since I wrote my last Ionic app. The only thing I recall was whether you or not used the @IonicPage annotation. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/IonicPage/ I went without them because that caused issues, which I forget the specifics now. It may have since been fixed. I always used the Ionic CLI to create my pages: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate and everything worked fine.  You just had to make sure your **app.module.ts** had the references correctly applied and everything worked. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/IonicModule/

Comment: appretly this is actually a bug in ionic https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RxJS.

```
@Injectable({...})
class SomeService {
    private _testInt: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0); // initial value 0

    setTestInt(value: number) {
        this._testInt.next(value);
    }

    getTestInt(): Observable<number> {
        return this._testInt.asObservable();
    }
}

@Component({...})
class TestPage implements OnInit {
    public testInt: number;
    public testInt$: Observable<number>;
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // one way
        this.testInt$ = this.someService.getTestInt();

        // or another
        this.subscription = this.someService.getTestInt()
            .subscribe((value: number) => {
               this.testInt = value;
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

in the HTML:

```
<p>{{ testInt }}</p>
<p>{{ testInt$ | async }}</p>
```

If you are subscribing to a Observable, make sure you unsubscribe after the usage (usually On Destroy lifecycle hook).

Async Pipe does that out of the box.

Or try the ionViewWillEnter lifecycle hook.

As you can see in the official [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle): 
ngOnInit will only fire each time the page is freshly created, but not when navigated back to the page.

For instance, navigating between each page in a tabs interface will only call each page's ngOnInit method once, but not on subsequent visits.

ngOnDestroy will only fire when a page "popped". link That means that Page is cached, yes. Assigning value On Init will set the value only the first time page is visited and therefore not updated.

Comment: My problem is that the ngOnInit() is not called when i return to the page :S

Comment: It doesn't metter. With Observables, you'll always have the latest change.

Comment: I guess you are using Ionic 4? If not, previous versions don't have the same lifecycle hooks as Angular. ionDidLoad or something like that.

Comment: i am using ionic 4

Comment: As you can see in the official documentation:

ngOnInit will only fire each time the page is freshly created, but not when navigated back to the page. For instance, navigating between each page in a tabs interface will only call each page's ngOnInit method once, but not on subsequent visits. ngOnDestroy will only fire when a page "popped".

[link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)

That means that Page is cached, yes. Assigning value On Init will set the value only the first time page is visited and therefore not updated.

Comment: Preferably, you should try using the RxJS, as I already explained in the answer.

If not, you can try ionViewWillEnter or ionViewDidEnter lifecycle hooks.

Comment: I just tested, ionViewWillEnter works.
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yr6wdw) @MarcRasmussen

Comment: this is so odd that function is never called on mine :S

Comment: Which function is not called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197862/discussion-between-grizlizli-and-marc-rasmussen).